# How to use Lilypond's font in a LaTeX or PostScript file?

Tags: postscript, lilypond

How can I use Lilypond's font in a `LaTeX` or PostScript file?

I want to write chors using it, and I can't find the way on how to configure it.

Obs.: in a PostScript file, in mean as PostScript programming, like `/Lylipond-font findfont 20 scalefont setfont`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Pure PostScript programming, without using a TeX program, would be outside the scope of this site.

Comment: Another option would be to use the open-source Bravura music font, which matches the Unicode standard. You could select it using `fontspec`. http://www.smufl.org/fonts/

Answer (score 1):

The `lilyglyphs` package is designed to give you access to glyphs of the Emmentaler music font from within LaTeX, using the `fontspec` package (compiling with LuaLaTeX). See the package documentation (`texdoc lilyglyphs`). http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/latex/lilyglyphs